# Spring embedded LDAP get error: "No schema information returned by server, using default schema"

Tags: spring-ldap, apacheds

I start an embedded LDAP server using spring-security-ldap's ApacheDSContainer class, after LDIF imported, I try to connect LDAP server using Apache Directory Studio.
Then an error will popup:

```
Error while opening connection
- [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     SearchReques
- No schema information returned by server, using default schema.
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     SearchRequest
    baseDn : '2.5.4.3=schema'
    filter : '(2.5.4.0=subschema)'
    scope : base object
    typesOnly : false
    Size Limit : no limit
    Time Limit : no limit
    Deref Aliases : deref Always
    attributes : 'objectclasses', 'attributetypes', 'ldapsyntaxes', 'matchingrules', 'matchingruleuse', 'createtimestamp', 'modifytimestamp'
:  Cannot find a partition for 2.5.4.3=schema]; remaining name 'cn=schema'
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper$1.run(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:356)
at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1272)
at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1203)
at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.search(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:398)
at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.SearchRunnable.search(SearchRunnable.java:500)
at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ExportLdifJob.search(ExportLdifJob.java:226)
at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ReloadSchemaRunnable.reloadSchema(ReloadSchemaRunnable.java:175)
at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.BrowserConnectionListener.openBrowserConnection(BrowserConnectionListener.java:115)
at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.BrowserConnectionListener.connectionOpened(BrowserConnectionListener.java:65)
at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.OpenConnectionsRunnable.runNotification(OpenConnectionsRunnable.java:132)
at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.StudioConnectionJob.run(StudioConnectionJob.java:120)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

[LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     SearchRequest
    baseDn : '2.5.4.3=schema'
    filter : '(2.5.4.0=subschema)'
    scope : base object
    typesOnly : false
    Size Limit : no limit
    Time Limit : no limit
    Deref Aliases : deref Always
    attributes : 'objectclasses', 'attributetypes', 'ldapsyntaxes', 'matchingrules', 'matchingruleuse', 'createtimestamp', 'modifytimestamp'
:  Cannot find a partition for 2.5.4.3=schema]
No schema information returned by server, using default schema.
```

If I ignore the error, all function works good

Answer (score 0):

I think you are providing the wrong base dn and the wrong filter.

```
baseDn : '2.5.4.3=schema'
filter : '(2.5.4.0=subschema)'
```

Try to check the parameters of the ADS connection